# Issues with PowerApps since end of August 2021

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps, powerapps-formula

I have been using PowerApps for a couple of years now to create simple user interfaces with SharePoint lists as the database.

Since last week I have started to experience a number of issues with my apps. For example, when referencing a SharePoint list single line of text column by its field name, PowerApps says that it doesn't recognise the identifier. I use the exact same formula for a different single line of text column in the same database and it works fine.

I have a gallery that I have added a couple of extra label fields to. The formula that I am using is simply 'ThisItem.ColumnName'. For one that works this is 'ThisItem.Address' and this displays the address which comes from a single line of text column. One that doesn't work is 'ThisItem.Industry'. The internal field name for the column is definitely Industry and it is definitely also a single line of text column. In the label itself I have switched between both formulas and again the Address column displays fine but the Industry column is not recognised.

I have further tried:

- Recreating the database from scratch
- Deleting the column/s that aren't being recognised and recreating them
- Refreshing the data connections, including deleting and re-adding
- Using Edge instead of Chrome
- Creating a database on a different teamsite (same site collection tho)
- Turning off all experimental features in the settings

I would upload some screenshots but as this is my first post, I'm not allowed to....

Has anyone else experienced anything similar? Anyone able to provide some insight as to why this has suddenly started occurring? HELP, anyone????

Thanks in advance.

Shannon

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you still don't have enough rep to upload images, and this may be a product bug, you can try posting a question in the Power Apps community at https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/bd-p/PowerAppsForum1. There you should be able to upload images, and have either someone in the community or from the product team answer your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

So i found what was causing the issue, still in the dark as to why though.

The gallery is linked to multiple databases (sharePoint lists) through an IF statement. The user selects a district from a drop down box and depending on what they select, the gallery is filtered using this IF statement.

The weird thing is, that the filter on the gallery works perfectly fine and displays all the records from that database. But for some reason, it only chooses to recognise a select few of the columns within that database.

When i removed the IF statement and just linked up one database, it works perfectly fine and all columns are recognised and display fine.

So, back to the drawing board on this one. At least i know now that i need to rework my gallery set up and that it isn't a case of corruption with the app or the database (that was my biggest fear!)

Hope this info provides some help if anyone else experiences this same issue.